# How to iterate sample users along with endpoint & payload while calling each API post request

Tags: python-3.x, csv, python-requests

[Original question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72034824/zip-lists-dict-list-of-unequal-length-to-compose-api-calls):
There are two functions:

- `ReadInp() -> Dict[str, str]` This reads a csv and returns a dict with a url as key and a payload as the value.
- `ReadTUsr() -> List[List[str, str]]` This reads a separate csv and returns 'sample users' as a list of lists. Each inner list is an id type and an id value. For instance:

`[['uId', 'T1'], ['srId', 'T2'], ['siId', 'T3'], ['siId', 'T4'], ['srId', 'T5']...]`

I need to make url calls that join these two values. The url being called will come from the first return value, but it must splice in the sample user from the second list. These lists may not be the same size, and if the second is exhausted before the first it should iterate again over the list until the first is exhausted.

For instance, the resultant calls would be like:

`http://localhost:8080/cabApp/callcab?uId=T1`
then POST body:
`{'location': '', 'ppl': '2', 'text': 'MyCab'}`

Or:

`http://localhost:8080/cabApp/call3cab?srId=T2` then POST body: `{'display': 'RMP', 'time': '', 'location': 'LA'}`

This is what I have tried: **Trial 1**

```
def makeAcall():

    r = ReadInp() # gives dict with endpoint as key and payload as Value 
    # This dict looks like this >> {'cabApp/callcab': {'location': '', 'ppl': '2', 'text': 'MyCab'}, 'cabApp/call3cab': {'display': 'RMP', 'time': '', 'location': 'LA'}, ...}  

    t = ReadTUsr() # give nested user list 
   # This list looks like this >> [['uId', 'T1'], ['srId', 'T2'], ['siId', 'T3'], ['siId', 'T4'], ['srId', 'T5']...]
    print(t)
    print(type(r))

    #for k1,v1 in r.items():
    #    for i,j in t:
    
    for (k1,v1), (i,j) in zip(r.items(), t):

        url = f"{AURL}(k1)}"
        rj = v1
        #uid = {"uId": "T1"}
        headers = {'Accept': "application/json"}
        res = requests.post(url, json=rj, headers=headers, params=(i,j))

        print("Req Resp Code:",res.status_code)
        #api_req_res_text.append(res.text)
        api_req_res_code.append(res.status_code)
    
    return api_req_res_code
```

**Trial 2**

```
def equalize_lists(users: list, desired_length) -> list:
    if len(users) > desired_length:
        return users[:desired_length]
    else:  # We need to extend the user list
        #repeat, extra = (desired_length // len(users), desired_length % len(users))
        repeat, extra = divmod(desired_length, len(users))
        users *= repeat + (extra > 0)
        #for _ in range(repeat):
            #users.extend(users)
        #users.extend(users[:extra])
        return users

def makeAcall():
    r = ReadInp() # gives dict with endpoint as key and payload as Value 
    # This dict looks like this >> {'cabApp/callcab': {'location': '', 'ppl': '2', 'text': 'MyCab'}, 'cabApp/call3cab': {'display': 'RMP', 'time': '', 'location': 'LA'}, ...}  

    t = ReadTUsr() # give nested user list 
   # This list looks like this >> [['uId', 'T1'], ['srId', 'T2'], ['siId', 'T3'], ['siId', 'T4'], ['srId', 'T5']...]
    print(t)
    print(type(r))
    
    users = equalize_lists(t, len(r))
    #users *= repeat + (extra > 0)
    for ((k1, v1), (i, j)) in (zip(r.items(), users)):
    
        url = f"{AURL}{k1}"
        rj = v1
        headers = {'Accept': "application/json"}
        res = requests.post(url, json=rj, headers=headers, params=(i,j))
        
        #uid = cycle(t)
        print("Req Resp Code:",res.status_code)
        #api_req_res_text.append(res.text)
        api_req_res_code.append(res.status_code)
    
    return api_req_res_code
```

- **Note1**: This is how my dict looks like `{'cabApp/callcab1': {'location': '', 'ppl': '2', 'text': 'MyCab'}, 'cab2App/call2cab2': {'ppl': '', 'text': 'Cab2'}, 'cabApp/call3cab': {'display': 'RMP', 'time': '', 'location': 'LA'}...}`
  Here *cabApp/callcab1*, *cab2App/call2cab2* & *cabApp/call3cab* are keys, which are endpoints[iterated as *k1* in code] and rest all is their individual payloads [iterated as *v1*] respectively. *http://localhost:8080* part is stored in *AURL* and is static. I can not update the code which builds the API as per the instruction[*res* where I am making the post request]. What I am searching for is the way to iterate list and use it as value after *param*.
- **Note2**: We can change the way it read sample users csv. Right now I am using this code to read sample users csv which gives nested list.

```
def ReadTUsr():
    with open(T_U_csv, 'r') as file:
        csv_file = csv.reader(file)
        data = [it for it in csv_file]
        #print(data)
        return data
```

- **Note3**: Earlier *ReadTUsr()* was dict and was working as expected (was able to iterate and call new sample user for each request) but latest code has duplicate keys in dict (multiple times *siId* & *srId*) so it only takes one record from duplicate keys which is default python behavior.
- **Que** How to iterate *sample users* (i,j) along with *endpoint & payload* (k1,v1) while calling each post request for *res* variable.

Comment: Problem is this for the line `res = requests.post(url, json=rj, headers=headers, params=(i,j))` >> `in _encode_params  for k, vs in to_key_val_list(data):ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` And that for loop from +makeAcall+ is not iterating over next key value pair :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def equalize_lists(users: list, desired_length) -> list:
    if len(users) > desired_length:
        return users[:desired_length]
    else:  # We need to extend the user list
        #repeat, extra = (desired_length // len(users), desired_length % len(users))
        repeat, extra = divmod(desired_length, len(users))
        users *= repeat + (extra > 0)
        #for _ in range(repeat):
            #users.extend(users)
        #users.extend(users[:extra])
        return users

def makeAcall():
    r = ReadInp() # gives dict with endpoint as key and payload as Value 
    # This dict looks like this >> {'cabApp/callcab': {'location': '', 'ppl': '2', 'text': 'MyCab'}, 'cabApp/call3cab': {'display': 'RMP', 'time': '', 'location': 'LA'}, ...}  

    t = ReadTUsr() # give nested user list 
   # This list looks like this >> [['uId', 'T1'], ['srId', 'T2'], ['siId', 'T3'], ['siId', 'T4'], ['srId', 'T5']...]
    print(t)
    print(type(r))
    
    users = equalize_lists(t, len(r))
    # or use this >> users = itertools.cycle(ReadInp())
    #users *= repeat + (extra > 0)
    for ((k1, v1), (i, j)) in (zip(r.items(), users)):
    
        url = f"{AURL}{k1}"
        rj = v1
        headers = {'Accept': "application/json"}
        res = requests.post(url, json=rj, headers=headers, params={i,j})
        
        #uid = cycle(t)
        print("Req Resp Code:",res.status_code)
        #api_req_res_text.append(res.text)
        api_req_res_code.append(res.status_code)
    
    return api_req_res_code
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).